# Regex for setting <img> src replaced with specific name

Tags: html

I have image tags in the form of

```
<img src="cid:imgName@01CAB53F.69BAB010"/>
```

here 01CAB53F.69BAB010 will change dynamically...I want to ignore things whatever comes after the imgName.

i want to replace it with

```
<img src="imgName"/>
```

if and only if the image take comes in the specified format..

I searched here , couldnt get the exact thing i need. I am new to regex.

I am using OpenPop to get mails. when reading mails, images are rendered in the specified format. so i have to store the image and replace it with the storedname.

can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

this regex will match all img tag followed by a src attribute

> ```
> (<img src=")[^"]+("/>)
> ```

and replace it by the value imgName ($1 and $2 stands for left and right part of img tag) :

> ```
> $imgName$2
> ```

do not forget to add the flag **g** (global)

Comment: hi i am totally a newbie to regex. can you provide an code with this usage in asp.net please?

Answer (score 0):

```
s/<img src="cid:(\w+)@[0-9A-F]+\.[0-9A-F]+\"\/>/<img src="$1"\/>/i
```

Comment: thank you for answering. as i already commented, i dont have ideas in regex. i want to implement the given solution in asp.net. can you please provide me an example in asp.net?